# Select min, max, avg, WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I'm using MySQL.

I'm trying to select the minumum, maximum and average length of a field but I'm not sure how. Something like this:

```
SELECT 
  min as min,
  max as max,
  avg as avg
FROM COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME like '%password%'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to find stats on the lengths of _column names_ or _column values_?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select
    column_name,
    min(length(column_name)) as min,
    max(length(column_name)) as max,
    avg(length(column_name)) as avg
from columns
where column_name like '%password%'
group by column_name
```

Comment: This is sort of what I want but for every row returned. When I do     SELECT * FROM COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%password%' it returns 100 records. How do I get the min, max, avg for every record? The column COLUMN_NAME contains the name of every column in my database.

Comment: @Alias add `GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME` in the end of your query.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Min(COLUMN_NAME), 
       Max(COLUMN_NAME), 
       Avg(COLUMN_NAME) 
  FROM TABLENAME 
 WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%password%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Min(MENTION_COLUMN_NAME_HERE) AS minimum_value, 
       Max(MENTION_COLUMN_NAME_HERE) AS maximum_value, 
       Avg(MENTION_COLUMN_NAME_HERE) AS average_value 
  FROM COLUMNS 
 WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%passord%'
```